# A different code for each custom post type + original post type 'posts'

Tags: php, wordpress

I have several custom posts types (albums, reviews, filmes and livros). On the index.php there's a loop where I need to show all of that content, with a "load more posts".

Here's how it looks right now:

[image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1O01J.png)

The problem is, I can't get the "post" post type to work. I'm using conditional tags to give write whatever I want in each one of them, but when I tried to do the same with posts, none of the exemples I've found worked.

Here's how the normal posts looks like:
[image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RP2OX.png)

There will be a lot more of them then these custom post types.

Each post type has it's own information I need to display. The printscreen is to have an idea of what it all looks like. Even better: here's the code.

```
      <section id="moreposts">
    <h3>Leia mais</h3>
    <div class="row" data-masonry='{ "itemSelector": ".col-md-3" }'>
            <?php $temp_query = clone $wp_query; ?><?php query_posts("showposts=12&post_type=any"); ?>
            <?php if (have_posts()) : ?>
            <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

            <?php if ( is_singular('post') )  { ?>
                post type POST
            <?php } ?>

            <?php if ( 'reviews' == get_post_type() ) { ?>
                post type REVIEWS
            <?php } ?>

            <?php if ( 'album' == get_post_type() ) { ?>
                post type ALBUM
            <?php } ?>

            <?php if ( 'filmes' == get_post_type() ) { ?>
                post type FILMES
            <?php } ?>

            <?php if ( 'livros' == get_post_type() ) { ?>
                post type LIVROS
            <?php } ?>

            <?php endwhile; ?><?php endif; ?><?php $wp_query = clone $temp_query; ?><?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
    </div>

            <button href="#fakelink" class="btn btn-block btn-lg btn-round btn-danger"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp; Carregar mais posts</button>
  </section>
```

So, does anyone know how to help me, pretty please? :)

Comment: I just had a cursory look at your code, but for your own debugging capabilities and for getting help faster, please reduce your code to the minimum that demonstrates your problem. This debugging technique is called [mcve]

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, your code is working perfectly fine with the exception of displaying posts with the post type of  `post`.

`is_singular()` checks to see if the current page is a single `page`, `post`, or `attachment`, but it doesn't check the post type. See more [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_singular).

Have you tried using the same `get_post_type()` check?

```
<?php if ( 'post' == get_post_type() ) { ?>
```

Let me know if I'm misunderstanding something here.

Comment: Yea, I used that same one on the others. the "is_singular" is only there cuz it was my last try lol

Comment: @PedroPauloOliveira please try again! Also before the conditionals, add `echo get_post_type();` so you can see what is being returned.  the code should work.